# How to reimplement UIScrollView paging using UIScrollViewDelegate methods

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uiscrollviewdelegate

For some reason, the `pagingEnabled` of UIScrollView does not fit my demand, I need to set the contentOffset manually. So first I need to reimplement paging, and then try to find out how to customize it.

Is it possible to reimplement UIScrollview paging only use UIScrollViewDelegate methods? And are there any examples?

Comment: I believe so, please provide more detail of what you are trying to accomplish and why it currently doesn't work for you and we can provide more specific information

Comment: Have you considered trying a different approach, like using `UIPageViewController` instead? See Apple's PhotoScroller sample code [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PhotoScroller/Introduction/Intro.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found [DMPagingScrollView](https://github.com/fumoboy007/DMPagingScrollView) that actually completely implement paging just using UIScrollView's delegate methods. It works just like a UIScrollView with paging enabled, and much more flexible.